# How to get a specific field within another django model?

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to get a specific field in a django model which is referenced through foreignkey.
Here is my views.py file:

```
def add_watchlist(request, name):
    stuff = Watchlist()
    thing = listing.objects.get(title = name)
    id = thing.id
    stuff.listing_id = id
    stuff.user = request.user
    stuff.save()
    things=Watchlist.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html",{
        "items":things
    })
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Cool kid {self.username}"

class listing(models.Model):
    creator=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")
    price=models.IntegerField()
    title=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=2056)
    src=models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} goes for a price of {self.price}, put forth by {self.creator} and here's the description: {self.description}"

class bid(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bidder")
    price=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} bid {self.price}"


class comment(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user=models.ForeignKey

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    listing=models.ForeignKey(listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} adds {self.listing.title} to the watchlist"
```

I hope to be able to find the title of the listing model and display it through html on watchlist. So far, I've only been able to display the whole listing model. Here is my watchlist.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Watchlist</h2>
    {% for item in items %}
    <ul>
        {{item.listing}}
    </ul>
    {%endfor%}
    TODO
{% endblock %}
```

{{item.listing.title}} is what I want, but that does not work.
I'm a beginner at django and am open to critiques, comments and clarifications.

Comment: when you try `{{item.listing.title}` what is the output you are getting ?

Comment: I get an error message

Comment: what error you are getting can share that here in your question